# Plot the independent variable x, as a function of fixed value of x

Tags: plotting

How can I plot a function to output a graph, that is defined on the x-axis by various instances of a fixed constant value `x`, where `x` is not a machine defined number?

For example,

```
Plot[2 + x b, {x, b/2, 2 b}]
```

is expected to plot a graph for various values of `x`, with `x = b / 2` as min, and `x = 2 b` as max values respectively.

Comment: The desired plot consists of the x-axis, is not defined as an array of numbers, rather as a function of b. Where, x, takes different iterations of b, from a min value of b/2 to 2b.

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Callout[ConditionalExpression[2 + x b, b/2 <= x <= 2 b], b], 
 {b, 0, 1, .1}]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Or with `PlotLabels`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[ConditionalExpression[2 + x b, b/2 <= x <= 2 b], {b, .2, 1, .2}]], 
 {x, 0, 2}, PlotLabels -> Range[.2, 1, .2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can plot them individually and combine by `Show`.

```
Show[Table[Plot[2 + x b, {x, b/2, 2 b}, PlotLabels -> b], {b, 1, 2, 0.1}], 
      PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

If you want a function which would give you the plot

```
plot[b_] := Plot[2 + x b, {x, b/2, 2 b}, PlotLabels -> b]

plot[2.3]
```

[image]

Comment: The desired plot consists of the x-axis, is not defined as an array of numbers, rather as a function of b. Where, x, takes different iterations of b, from a min value of b/2 to 2b.

Comment: Check my new answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If b is a varying parameter

```
Show[Table[Plot[2 + x.b, {x, b/2, 2 b}],{b,{bi,...}}]]
```

should solve your problem!